# Precedence in C operators == and ( = )

Tags: c, logical-operators, operator-precedence, assignment-operator

I have to analyze what some code in C does, and I have a doubt about what happens in a certain line. The code is

```
#define PRINTX printf("%d\n", x)

void problem() { 
    int x = 2, y, z;
    x *= 3 + 2; PRINTX;
    x *= y = z = 4; PRINTX;
    x = y == z; PRINTX;
    x == (y = z); PRINTX; // This line is the problem
}
```

This code snippet prints the resulting numbers:

```
10
40
1
1  // This result **
```

the problem is that I'm still trying to figure out why does the last line prints out **x = 1**, when the operation is `x == (y = z)`. I'm having trouble finding out what that 1 means and the precedence of the operations. Hope someone can help me! :)

Comment: Please never write horrible macros like `#define PRINTX printf("%d\n", x)`. Whoever taught you to do that shouldn't be teaching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing in the last statement changes the value of `x`, so its value remains unchanged.

---

Parens were used to override precedence, forcing the `=` to be the operand of the `==`.

An operator's operands must necessarily be evaluated before the operator itself, so we know the following:

- `y` is evaluated at some point before the `=`.
- `z` is evaluated at some point before the `=`.
- `x` is evaluated at some point before the `==`.
- `=` is evaluated at some point before `==`.

That's it. All of these are valid orders:

- `z` `y` `=` `x` `==`
- `y` `z` `=` `x` `==`
- `x` `y` `z` `=` `==`
- etc.

But whenever `x`, `y` and `z` are evaluated, we can count on the following happening:

1. `=` assigns the value of `z` (currently `4`) to `y` and returns it.
2. `==` compares the value of `x` (currently `1`) with the value returned by `=` (`4`). Since they're different, `==` returns `0` (which isn't used by anything).

As you see, nothing changed `x`, so it still has the value it previously had (`1`).

Answer (score 0):

In the last statement, nothing is changing the value of x. We are testing if x equals something, but we aren't changing it's value.

So it continues having the same value as it had in the previous statement, in particular, a value of 1.

Answer (score 0):

the reason is because the == operator checks if the 2 numbers are equal, and returns 1 if equal and 0 if not equal that is why it returns one you can check by making x= 1 and y=2 and using the == operator between them

Comment: The OP asking why `x` is `1` after *the last line*. You're explaining the second last line, which they don't seem to wonder about.

Answer (score 0):

The comparison result of `x` and assignment of `y` with `(y = z)` is discarded.  Last line could have dropped the compare: `y = z; PRINTX;`.

The assignment is not subsequently used either, so the line could have been `PRINTX;`.